# Setting up basic logging

Tags: azure-log-analytics, system-center

In azure log analytics we are reading windows logs from an onpremise server. We would like to setup some basic metricks, like disk, CPU, RAM etc to make sure it is running. However we have like thousands to choose from in Azure. Can someone recommend some basic performance counters to monitor, or link to some documentation?

[image]

Comment: Please refer [Configure Basic Logs in Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/basic-logs-configure?tabs=portal-1%2Cportal-2)

Comment: Also refer [Configuring Performance counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-performance-counters#configuring-performance-counters)

Answer (score 0):

> Setting up basic logging

- I have  created a Log Analytics Workspace and tried to add the Windows Performance Counters.
- Navigate to

Your  ***Log Analytics Workspace*** => ***Agents Configuration*** => Click on ***Add recommended counters*** and click on Apply , all the required basic counters will be added by default.

[image]

[image]

- We can add the performance counter one by one , based on your requirement

[image]

Please refer [Configure Basic Logs in Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/basic-logs-configure?tabs=portal-1%2Cportal-2)  and [Configuring Performance counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-performance-counters#configuring-performance-counters) for more information